# set individual cell Styles js-xlsx, xlsx-style node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

Can't find a way to style individual cells when writing to file. Reading is no problem though. Have tried either js-xlsx, xlsx-style, non seem to work? Or am I reading the API wrong? 
  If i read correctly it should be enough to set cell.s to an object like this

```
  { alignment: { horizontal: 'center', vertical: 'center' }, patternType: 'solid', bgColor: { indexed: 64 }, fgColor: { rgb: 'FFC6EFCE' } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it was not possible to style individual cells with js-xlsx. So I used a separate package for creating excel files **exceljs**